# I cannot redirect the buttons I created in jquery to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have to direct the add, delete, update buttons that I created with jquery to the controller, but I don't know how to give the URL link?

```
  $(function () {
        
                    var URL = "~/View/Mission";
        
                    var orders = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
                        key: "id",
                        load: function () {
                            return sendRequest(URL + "/Index");
                        },
                        insert: function (values) {
                            return sendRequest(URL + "/Create.cshtml", "POST", {
                                values: JSON.stringify(values)
                            });
                        },
                        update: function (key, values) {
                            return sendRequest(URL + "/Create.cshtml/key", "PUT", {
                                key: key,
                                values: JSON.stringify(values)
                            });
                        },
                        remove: function (key) {
                            return sendRequest(URL + "/Delete/key", "DELETE", {
                                key: key
                            });
                        }
                    });
    });
```

Comment: I would recommend to check this [source](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/CustomStore/Configuration/#insert)

Comment: Hi, a similar question has been asked here, and while it's using Knockout instead of jQuery and Asp.Net MVC instead of Core, but the answer should be still relevant and helpful to your use-case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965503/how-to-send-data-from-javascript-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-url